# What Is The Python 3 Equivalent to This

Tags: python, printing, trailing

What is the Python 3 equivalent to Python 2's statement:

```
print x,
```

I am aware of Python's 3

```
print(x,end=' ')
```

However this is not exactly the same as I will demonstrate.

So lets say I had a list of items I wanted to print out all on one line with spaces in between each item BUT NOT after the last item.

In Python 2 it is just simply:

```
for x in my_list:
    print x,
```

However if we use the Python 3 approach above it will produce the list of items on one line but will have trailing white space after the last item.

Does Python 3 have a nice elegant solution to produce the same results as in the Python 2 statement?

Comment: Use `join()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to print each element on their own, you can do:

```
print(' '.join(my_list))
```

or

```
print(*my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require the loop, you can just print it all at once:

```
print(" ".join(my_list))
```

Comment: a list doesn't have a `join` method, it's `' '.join(list)`

Comment: @Tordek Oh yes, thanks, I got it the wrong way round.